# Removing duplicates from list where duplication logic is based on custom field

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of following info

```
public class TheInfo {
    private int id;
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;
    private String fieldThree;
    private String fieldFour;

   //Standard Getters, Setters, Equals, Hashcode, ToString methods
}
```

The list is required to be processed in such a way that

1. Among duplicates, select the one with minimum ID, and remove others. In this particular case, entries are considered duplicate when their values of `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` are equal.
2. Get concatenated value of `fieldThree` and `fieldFour`.

I want to process this list Java8 Streams. Currently I don't know how to remove duplicates base on custom fields. I think I can't use `distinct()` because I can't change equals/hashcode method as logic is just for this specific case.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried?

Comment: Till now, I have wrapped `TheInfo` info into `TheWrapper` and implements `equals and `hascode` based on `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo`, + implemented `Comparable` based on `id`. After doing this, I mapped list of `TheInfo` to `TheWrapper`, sorted it, applied `distinct()`, mapped back to `TheInfo`, and collected as a List. I am currently testing it.

Comment: Though the implementation I mentioned in previous comment worked, Overridden `equals` didn't comply with the contract of `compareTo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
List<TheInfo> list;
```

you can use

```
List<TheInfo> result = new ArrayList<>(list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(info -> Arrays.asList(info.getFieldOne(), info.getFieldOne()),
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(TheInfo::getId)),
            Optional::get))).values());
```

the `groupingBy` collector produces groups according to a function whose results determine the equality. A list already implements this for a sequence of values, so `Arrays.asList(info.getFieldOne(), info.getFieldOne())` produces a suitable key. In Java 9, you would most probably use `List.of(info.getFieldOne(), info.getFieldOne())` instead.

The second argument to `groupingBy` is another collector determining how to process the groups, `Collectors.minBy(…)` will fold them to the minimum element according to a comparator and `Comparator.comparingInt(TheInfo::getId)` is the right comparator for getting the element with the minimum id.

Unfortunately, the `minBy` collector produces an `Optional` that would be empty if there are no elements, but since we know that the groups can’t be empty (groups without elements wouldn’t be created in the first place), we can unconditionally call `get` on the optional to retrieve the actual value. This is what wrapping this collector in `Collectors.collectingAndThen(…, Optional::get)` does.

Now, the result of the grouping is a `Map` mapping from the keys created by the function to the `TheInfo` instance with the minimum id. Calling `values()` on the `Map` gives as a `Collection<TheInfo>` and since you want a `List`, a final `new ArrayList<>(collection)` will produce it.

---

Thinking about it, this might be one of the cases, where the `toMap` collector is simpler to use, especially as the merging of the group elements doesn’t benefit from mutable reduction:

```
List<TheInfo> result = new ArrayList<>(list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        info -> Arrays.asList(info.getFieldOne(), info.getFieldOne()),
        Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(TheInfo::getId)))).values());
```

This uses the same function for determining the key and another function determining a single value, which is just an identity function and a reduction function that will be called, if a group has more than one element. This will again be a function returning the minimum according to the ID comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Using streams, you can process it using just the collector, if you provide it with proper classifier:

```
private static <T> T min(T first, T second, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
  return cmp.compare(first, second) <= 0 ? first : second;
}

private static void process(Collection<TheInfo> data) {
  Comparator<TheInfo> cmp = Comparator.comparing(info -> info.id);

  data.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                info -> Arrays.asList(info.fieldOne, info.fieldTwo), // Your classifier uses a tuple. Closest thing in JDK currently would be a list or some custom class. I chose List for brevity.
                info -> info, // or Function.identity()
                (a, b) -> min(a, b, cmp) // what do we do with duplicates. Currently we take min according to Comparator.
              ));
}
```

The above stream will be collected into `Map<List<String>, TheInfo>`, which will contain minimal element with lists of two strings as key. You can extract the `map.values()` and return then in new collection or whatever you need them for.